Is the anthropic principle a "cop-out"?
Forgive me in advance for the provocative title. It's likely I only have a pop-science understanding of the AP and there is something important I'm missing. That's why I'm asking the question!
My understanding of the anthropic principle is that it's a response to the apparent fine-tuning of the laws of physics. Given that some physical constants such as the strength of charge of an electron could seemingly be different to what they are, but if they had been only slightly different, organic life would have been impossible, it seems that our existence depends on a very very improbable state of affairs estimated at odds of thousands to one.
Sometimes it's said that this very improbable initial state demands an explanation: why did things turn out just as they did, in such a fashion as to allow stars, planets and organic life to exist, when the universe could just as easily have been nothing more than a big cloud of hydrogen?
The Anthropic Principle, as I understand it, is a response to this: The universe had to have had that improbable initial state, all those seemingly finely-tuned physical constants, because if it had not then we would not be here to ask the question why!
It seems to me that this is is a sort of non-answer. The curious child, or interested amateur, or physics professor, asks why the universe is so complex when it could have been very simple or non existent. Several answers are possible:

It was intentionally designed that way, whether by a bearded figure sitting on a cloud, a cosmic watchmaker or super-intelligent alien beings programming a simulation
There is some unknown constraint that meant the values of the strong and weak nuclear forces, etc, had to be as they are and not something else
There are many universes, so all possible values of physical parameters are instantiated, including the small number which allow for complex chemistry and organic life

The AP seems to address none of these possibilities and actively avoids them. It's a kind of non-answer: since we're already here, the universe had to allow for that, so why wonder about it, why not ask some other question instead? And it gives this non-answer in a way that seems to elevate human organic life from something contingent into something fundamental to the physical parameters of the universe.
Am I misunderstanding the issue, or is the AP not really scientific explanation?

Anthropic principle explicitly presupposes the third possibility bullet in the OP. It only works as an explanation when multiple universes with various values of constants are instantiated. This is mentioned even by Wikipedia.

Multiverse by itself does not explain the fine-tuning, only combining it with the anthropic argument does (we observe an atypical universe because typical ones lack observers).

Note that there are multiple forms of the anthropic principle. The weak AP and the strong AP are the most well-known.

The anthropic principle is often criticized as a "cop-out" because it suggests that the universe must be the way it is for us to observe it, without offering deeper explanations. While this argument explains why the universe allows life, it doesn't address how the conditions emerged. Critics argue that it sidesteps meaningful inquiry into cosmological origins, while proponents see it as a legitimate framework for understanding the universe’s fine-tuning.

"some physical constants [.. ] could seemingly be different to what they are" "this very improbable initial state" "the universe [...] could have been very simple" we don't know that. The anthropic principle itself is kind of a weak rebuttal, but the fine tuning theory on its own is based on very unwarranted assumptions and as such doesn't really need a rebuttal beyond contesting its premises.

The curious child, amateur and professor couldn’t possibly exist in a universe whose laws doesnt allow them to exist. Now we could have different fine tuning leading to a universe where entities capable of asking questions are totally different from us - but they must be able to exist snd ask questions or no questions get asked.

Great question! I edited to fortify it a bit. Feel free to roll back if you feel it undermines the essence of your question. :D

Cop out?  No not exactly.  It's just that the fine tuning argument doesn't require much of a reply as things stand.  It just means that no matter the probability of the events that led up to us existing, those events had to occur.
The main problem with the fine tuning argument is that we don't know exactly why things like electrons get their exact charge so it's hard to understand how they can be different, so calculating the probability's is difficult to begin with, so we're dealing with the calculation of probability's of things we don't fully understand.
We would also need to know the probability of the "designer" to compare.  So, we're comparing the probability of some natural event we understand poorly to the probability of a "designer" we don't understand at all.
Also, very low probability events happen all the time, and I can sit here and calculate the probably of me having exactly my genetic makeup considering only the pares of humans and the amount of spermatozoa involved and come to the conclusion that I am in fact sitting here is some absurdly low number and thus impossible without divine intervention, or I can realize that there needed to be such an outcome for me to be sitting here typing this reply.
So, we should be a little suspect of statements like:
x has a very low absolute probability of happening therefore God, which is the form of the fine tuning argument.

If it's a response to an argument from design, it seems better responses are possible.

It's a response to a poorly thought out probability argument for design.  The proper response to not knowing something is to investigate further.

"It just means that no matter the probability of the events that led up to us existing,  - those events had to occur" Seems to me more like, "those events had to be possible". I mean, it's improbable that I might win a lottery, but if I did win it and then said "it had to occur" then I'm claiming that it was predestined somehow.

The probability that I win the lottery is different than the probability that someone would.

I wouldn't, for instance, after winning the lottery, immediately doubt that it was possible to do so randomly.

We know how lotteries work, so randomness is not surprising, we don't know how universes work (at least as far as how physical constants get their values is concerned), so randomness might be involved or might not. But asking about it is a legitimate question. "It's a mystery", or "We don't know yet", or "We can't know" are all legitimate answers.

It's a legitimate question yes.  And "we don't know" is a good answer.  However, "fine tuning" also a very poor argument for design which is how the argument is usually used.  The anthropic principle is something to keep in mind when people start trying to demonstrate that our existence is wildly improbable based upon information they can't possibly know.

@KristianBerry indeed we don't know, maybe it's not possible. But if it were possible, non-physical beings, being non-physical, probably would not be made of anything!

@KristianBerry I guess there could be infinite Gods and we just happen to be living in the universe created by the one wise enough and powerful enough to be able to create universes, otherwise we wouldn't be here having this conversation!

"It just means that no matter the probability of the events that led up to us existing, those events had to occur." That much is obvious, but it doesn't address causation and sure feels like a copout to me.  And circular reasoning...

It certainly dosent addresses the various probabilities we don't know how to derive so there's nothing to cop to in the first place.

I prefer to think about this in the same way as the "gambling oracle" scam or whatever it might be called.

Basically: I will tell x·2n people that I will predict the result of n+1 sport events. At each time I will send out "home team won" to half the remaining people, and "guest team won" to half of them. After the game I won't send anything more to the ones that got the wrong result.
At the end x people will believe that I correctly guessed all events, and then I want them to pay me $1000 for giving them the result of the next game, which I will also guess.

The fact that we exist to ask the question means that we "correctly guessed the games" up until now.
Whether or not the universe had 2n chances or guessed right from the start doesn't make a lot of difference.

I agree that the anthropic principle is pretty worthless, but ... half of the remaining x will be pretty disappointed that you "suddenly" gave the wrong answer after that "highly improbably", "impossible-without-secret-knowledge-or-foresight" stretch of previous predictions... Suggestion: Just ask them to pay one more time, for the next game, since this was just a fluke wrong guess "of course"! In fact, instead of dropping half your respondents, originally, try to keep at least part of the other half around too, for a while. This way your population need not shrink exponentially :)

You could generalise your answer a little, I think, to give more context to the example. E.g.: "It's worth noting that this principle is also significant (and more demonstrably so) in domains other than cosmology - people are naturally prone to ascribing significance to apparent patterns."

Douglas Adams' puddle analogy does a good job of explaining it.

This is rather as if you imagine a puddle waking up one morning and thinking, 'This is an interesting world I find myself in - an interesting hole I find myself in - fits me rather neatly, doesn't it? In fact it fits me staggeringly well, must have been made to have me in it!'

The physical constants aren't fine tuned for us: they came first. We're fine-tuned for them. If the constants had been different, we wouldn't exist, certainly. Something else would exist instead, and that thing would then be able to say that the physical constants of its universe appear to be perfectly fine-tuned to it, and if they'd been even slightly different (such as, for example, they way they are in our universe), it wouldn't be able to exist.
Now, that explains why it doesn't matter how unlikely it is that we specifically exist, but there does remain the question of how likely it is that a random set of physical constants would permit some form of intelligence that could ask that question. And we really have no idea how know how likely that is (we don't even know how likely intelligence is in this universe). We also don't know if reality only gets one shot at generating a set of physical constants that can do that or if it gets lots of attempts. Depending on the answers to those questions, it could be either exceedingly unlikely that intelligence would arise anywhere or almost certain. We simply don't know yet.

Seems like the assumption is that the odds of a universe capable of supporting any kind of intelligence, or even basic chemistry, are staggeringly low. So it's not so much the puddle amazed that the hole fits him so well, more that the puddle is amazed that anything exists at all.

@MisterMiyagi, No, Batperson is correct, the fine tuning argument is "amazed that anything exists at all."  Not just intelligent life, but atoms, stars, galaxies, etc.  The existence of ALL known matter relies on a series of incredibly fine tuned natural laws.

@MisterMiyagi, you are splitting hairs then because "anything at all" implies anything we know about.  Because the fine tuning argument doesn't argue for a multiverse that is NOT known to us, in fact it argues the opposite.

@MisterMiyagi So by "instead of another" are you saying that the AP does not presuppose a multiverse?

@MisterMiyagi But if you are correcting somebody you owe it to them to be precise with your words, otherwise simply allow them the same courtesy of "sloppy" wording such as "anything" to mean "our universe" or anything known to us.  Cheers.

@MisterMiyagi, and we are right back to the beginning...  I stand by my first counterpoint above.

Wonderful quote (Derek Mathias, Quora): 'Our universe is far more "finely tuned" for creating black holes than it is for supporting life.'

@MichaelHall "The existence of ALL known matter relies on a series of incredibly fine tuned natural laws." - Can you cite anything to support the idea that stable molecules other than the specific ones we have could not exist if you tweaked the constants? Suppose we increased the gravitational constant by 20%. There would still presumably be a point at which a carbon and hydrogen atom (or something like them) would have their attractive and repulsive forces at equilibrium. Wouldn't necessarily function like the hydrocarbons we have currently, but it would still be a something, no?

@Ray, I don't have a single source document, but have read numerous articles over the years.

In his book The Biotic Message: Evolution Versus Message Theory (pp. 61-66, c1993), Walter James ReMine lists three formulations of the anthropic principle, and explains issues with each:

The tautological anthropic principle: Stated as, "The universe has survivable (and observable) properties because we survive (and observe)."  To quote ReMine a little later, "Does our survival cause the universe to have survivable properties?  Yes, in a trivial linguistic sense, it 'causes' it to be true by definition."  But tautologies and definitions are not explanatory by themselves; and this doesn't explain why the universe is survivable to being with.
The metaphysical anthropic principle: The idea of the multiverse.  ReMine says this is "the only [formulation listed] having any explanatory power."  ReMine says that because these "other universes" are not observable, they "smack of non-science."  It is conjecture, without any observable scientific evidence.
The 'lame' anthropic principle: ReMine says that this formulation does not even attempt to explain the issue.  He gives the following quote by Barrow and Tipler, 1988 The Anthropic Cosmological Principle, as an illustration if taken "precisely as it stands" (italics by Barrow and Tipler): "The observed values of all physical and cosmological quantities are not equally probable but they take on values restricted by the requirement that there exist sites where carbon-based life can evolve and by the requirement that the Universe be old enough for it to have already done so."  ReMine compares this answer by saying, if you ask "Why is the sky blue?", their response would be akin to, "The observed color of the sky is restricted by the requirement that it be blue."  ReMine goes on, "Their formulation simply does not explain the problem."

ReMine closes the section by stating how it's possible to shift back and forth between formulations to avoid criticism on any one particular way of stating it:

Ambiguity serves the purpose of allowing theorists to shift effortlessly away from any single line of criticism.  If you argue it is tautological, they can shift to either a metaphysical or lame formulation.  If you argue it is lame, they can shift to either a tautological or metaphysical formulation.  This ability to shift back and forth is key to the illusions about the anthropic principle.


In that case, why not say that it's tautological, metaphysical and lame? Or even: it's lame because it's metaphysically tautological!

@PeterRankin "in a trivial linguistic sense, it 'causes' it" -- so, you mean it implies it? The problem being, implication doesn't mean causality, and we would like causality.

@NicolWollaston If I understand ReMine correctly, I think he's being a little tongue-in-cheek by using similar terminology to those he's heard use the tautological formulation in the place of a causal explanation.  I think he's saying it only "causes" it if you stretch the meaning of the word to be in a purely linguistic sense, which you're right, isn't actually causal.  But I think that's ReMine's point.

@PeterRankin Right, I agree with ReMine that the multiverse anthropic principle seems to explain more than the other versions. I am just never sure if I am missing some hidden logic when people keep mixing them up.

The comparison  being made in the 'lame' AP example seems flawed.  To me the real question should be "what are the odds we observe a blue sky?"  Which is not so straightforward to answer.  You could, for instance, calculate what % of planets have blue skies, but that wouldn't really work because it wouldn't account for life arising on those planets.  It then raises the question "could our life have evolved from a non-blue-skied planet at all?" Which arguably is a simple "no" because we wouldn't be us if conditions were different enough to change the sky colour.

+1 for quoted source, plus a clean explanation of these distinct versions of AP. A mild criticism of ReMine: the 'lame' AP seems to primarily be a strawman, and doesn't address most AP proponents. Also, ReMine wrongly assumes tautologies cannot be explanatory; albeit yes, tauto AP doesn't explain Fine Tuning. Although meta AP does direly need evidence, it's the primary counter to the Intelligent Design explanation for Fine Tuning, and there are few alternatives. Meta AP is at least supported by the Everett interpretation of QM, meanwhile "god did it" has a very bad track record in science.

"Although meta AP does direly need evidence, it's the primary counter to the Intelligent Design explanation for Fine Tuning" smacks of a pure fabrication to avoid facing something science would rather not try to deal with.

@MichaelHall Many scientists take multiverse theories very seriously; saying they'd "rather not ... deal with [it]" is objectively false. Either way, evidence is needed from all sides. The difference between MAP and ID is that multiverse is supported by the math of our best theories, and easily explains fine tuning. By contrast, ID is supported by nothing concrete, and positing a universe-creator enables the possibility they create multiple universes, i.e. a multiverse. The designer in ID is ineffective at explaining Fine Tuning, because multiverse does all the heavy lifting either way.

(cont.) My point wasn't that MAP is believable; my point is that it's a (very effective) direct response to the ID argument from fine tuning. That is my criticism of ReMine, that he misses the context & purpose of MAP. MAP doesn't need to be believable in any absolute sense, it just needs to be strictly more believable than ID, and it is. ID plausibly supports multiverse, but not vice versa, so MAP is strictly more plausible. Since MAP explains fine tuning, and MAP is strictly more plausible than ID, then fine tuning cannot be used as an argument in favor of ID (since MAP supersedes).

@JadeVanadium, we are both saying that the idea of a multiverse was invented to counter creationism, we are simply using different terminology. Believability is purely a matter of personal opinion, and is precisely why this will never be settled.

@MichaelHall Well, the anthropic principle was invented to counter creationism, sure, but multiverse theories have appeared multiple times, on their own terms, in several unrelated branches of science. I'd go on but this is getting pretty off topic so let's just leave it at that.

The argument that the AP responds to considers a set of hypothetical universes with different universal constants. To do so, it relies on two important implicit assumptions:

"Possible" universes follow, in principle, the same laws as the observable universe, just with different values for certain "parameters", e.g. the charge of an electron.

The probability distribution of these parameters can be calculated or at least estimated.


In reality, we have no evidence of any of these assumptions being true or more likely than any other. There is no reason to assume that concepts like "electron" and "charge" make any sense in a random hypothetical universe except for the fact that they do in ours. And even if we assume that they do, the methods we use to guess these probabilities are based on our understanding of our universe.
The AP is, in SE terms, a frame challenge. It points out that the question has implicit assumptions, and that these assumptions are based on how our universe works. In a very different universe, the question would be very different.
Of course "why isn't the universe different?" is a valid question to ask, but going further and assigning probabilities to different configurations requires you to make these "biased" assumptions.
In essence, it's not that "the universe's psrameters are tuned for intelligent life to exist" but rather, "this question is tuned by the universe's parameters (and would not exist in this form in a different hypothetical universe)."

Having read through the various answers to my question (thanks everyone) I'm convinced that the value of the AP is that it gets us to consider the possibility of multiple universes and the implications of that. In that context it has some potential explanatory power, assuming multiple universes could be demonstrated to exist somehow.

I can also envisage a conversation like this: "Granted, fine-tuning seems like the universe could be the work of an intelligent being. But what makes you so certain that intelligent being just happens to be the Christian God of your particular denomination?" "Oh, that's easy. There are an infinite number of Gods that create universes, and there are also universes that come into existence by themselves without a God as well. So it's not surprising one of those universes happens to have been created by the God I believe in! I just have faith that that's the one we are in right now!"

@Batperson, "it has some potential explanatory power, assuming multiple universes could be demonstrated to exist somehow" Well... couldn't you say that about almost any made up thing?  Because Pixie Dust also has "potential explanatory power"...  IF it "could be demonstrated to exist somehow".  The trouble is that is a mighty big if, and the hypothesis lacks any evidence.

It's the Atheist's equivalent to "Creating Hell"
I recall once reading something written by Augustine, on the question of what God was doing before the creation of the Universe:

I do not answer, as some do, that he was creating Hell for those who
ask such questions. Because...

And the rest of the paragraph amounted to, more or less, that that was avoiding the question, and that since time was a property of the universe, there could not have been a "before".
It seems to me that the Anthropic Principle has similar characteristics to "He was creating Hell". Not the implication that the questioner should be ashamed or fearful, but the other characteristics, of giving a non-answer, a rhetorical dodge.
It seems that existential-type questions might not be answerable, and certainly can't be answered at this point with anything beyond speculation, but speculation that proposes a hypothesis is legitimate and allows for follow up of some kind. If this seems an unprofitable use of time, "I don't know" or "Nobody knows yet" are also legitimate answers.
A response which discourages further questions, feels to me like an illegitimate answer.

I'm a physicist, not a philosopher, so I'll just offer some thoughts about how I see this issue perceived in the physics community.
The anthropic principle is intentionally very vague about metaphysical details in order to get the broadest possible acceptance base.  (In this, it is a lot like the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics, but I won't digress on that point.)  Obviously, humans will only be around to ask questions about their own existence in a universe that makes their existence possible.  On the other hand, this restricts you to the question "What is the 'probability' that the universe is the way it is, given that it contains humans?" rather than the broader question "Why is the universe the way it is?"
Now, my feeling is that a majority of working physicists believe the following from the question:

There are many universes, so all possible values of physical parameters are instantiated, including the small number which allow for complex chemistry and organic life.

This is particularly true for string theorists, who have been the biggest advocates of the anthropic principle as an answer to the string theory landscape problem.  However, there is a substantial minority of theistic physicists who might see fine-tuning as evidence of intelligent design.
Note that there are also a lot of physicists who believe in your second option (that there is some principle that constrains the laws of physics to be as they are), but I think that this partially begs the question and partially is unrelated to the anthropic principle.  It begs the question because you can always ask, "Why that particular principle rather than another?"  And it's unrelated because the premise is not really related to the existence of humans at all.
Finally, I should say that from my own personal perspective, I think that most discussions of the anthropic principle are very parochial on two points:

We tend to imagine that life can only consist of the type of organic matter we see in our universe.
We only consider the effects on physical formations (atoms, molecules, solar systems, galaxies) that exist in our universe but do not consider physical formations that could exist in universes with other parameters but do not exist in our universe.

The requirements for the evolution of life are very simple: self-replication, mutation, and natural selection.  I think that these ingredients can probably be found in a wide variety of physical systems.  I have no doubt that if you take the Standard Model of our physics and twiddle with parameters, there will be many parameter combinations that result in very "boring" universes.  But I also expect that there are many choices of physical parameters that result in life, but just not life in the same way that it exists on Earth.  (It also seems perfectly plausible to me that there are life forms in our universe that do not resemble life on Earth, but that's equally speculative.)

+1 Thanks for the contribution! Physics commenting on the philosophy of physics is generally more productive. ; ) You say: "The requirements for the evolution of life are very simple: self-replication, mutation, and natural selection." I would add to this list the condition that the physical systems in question must evolve into a dynamic equilibrium that meets some minimum standard of the description of life according to biologists. But I nitpick.

From an ideal Bayesian perspective, the Anthropic Principle might potentially be used to increase the prior probability of a hypothesis about the universe. In brief, it might be possible to use the assumption that the universe must contain intelligent life, to more concisely describe the universe. (And more concise explanations are more likely, assuming they match all the observations.)
It's a bit subtle, and there's a strong possibility that the Anthropic Principle is not helpful at all.

A brief explanation of ideal Bayesian inference:
Ideally, a Bayesian agent begins with a prior probability distribution across all possible explanations of the whole universe. These explanations consist of computer programs in a minimal language (e.g. specifications of Turing machines). Each program generates a complete sequence of all observations that will ever be seen. Unless two programs generate the exact same sequence of observations, they are mutually exclusive.
The prior probability of a computer program is proportional to exp(-L) where L is the length in bits of the program. This is the Minimum Description Length prior, because it strongly rewards the shortest programs.
As observations arrive, the agent crosses out every computer program that fails to generate the exact sequence of observations seen so far. The shortest programs that have not been crossed out are the most likely explanations for the observations.

So how does this relate to the Anthropic Principle?
Well, it's conceivable that we might use the Anthropic Principle to write a computer program that describes our observations, which happens to be shorter than computer programs that don't rely on the Anthropic Principle. The program without the Anthropic Principle might go something like this:
Generate a large set of possible universes according to simple rules
N = 124039495098734598767110238... // note: this number keeps going for a while (not shown)
return a sequence of observations based on universe number N from the set

N is long because it encodes (among other things) the exact values for all the universal constants. N occupies most of the space of the program.
Now compare this to a program using the Anthropic Principle to select only those universes that have intelligent life:
Generate a large set of possible universes according to simple rules
N = 4235 // relatively small N, saving space
i = 0
Loop over each universe
  if the universe contains intelligent life: // imagine we have some concise algorithm to check if this is true
    i++
    if i == N:
      return a sequence of observations based on this particular universe

The second program's value of N is much smaller than the first program's value of N, because the "test for intelligent life" filters out almost all of the initially generated universes (if we assume that almost all of the initially generated universes do not have intelligent life). This reduction in the size of N saves some space in the program.
This is counterbalanced by the complexity of the algorithm used to "test for intelligent life." The second program only "wins" if the amount of bits used in the algorithm to "test for intelligent life" is smaller than the reduction in the size of N.
These are some big "ifs." For example, if there's an algorithm to test for intelligent life that requires, say, only 1000 bits of code, and if intelligent life is only present in fewer than 1 in 2^1000 of the generated universes, then the second program based on the Anthropic Principle wins. Are those kinds of numbers plausible?

I don't know that I have any reason to trust that number of bits in human-written representative code corresponds to what's true in any form, especially given that it ignores time complexity (which seems to disregard important aspects of explanatory power: "surprising facts" and predictive power, since a loop can find even the most improbable things). It's also worth noting that you're comparing it basically to those things being true as a brute fact (us not having an explanation), rather than comparing it to "God did it" (the question doesn't explicitly ask that, but fine-tuning implies it).

@NotThatGuy In the Bayesian formulation, "God Did It" would come in the form of a computer program that specifies an intelligent entity which then generates this exact universe. That might actually have a similar program length to program #2 above, as they both need to somehow specify what an intelligent entity is. Although the extra challenge of a "God Did It" explanation, beyond the complexity of specifying your entity, is showing why the intelligent entity you specified would create this specific universe instead of some other one.

@causative: obviously the intelligent entity created a vast number of universes, possibly infinite, in which case the fact that He happened to create this specific one is not surprising and needs no further explanation!

@Batperson No, it does. The Bayesian agent is trying to find a computer program that exactly generates all and only his observations. If the computer program gives him a billion - or infinite - possible universes, it fails at that task, because it does not output all and only his observations. To succeed at the task, the program must select a single universe (and in fact also a single point of view within that universe). In the examples, that's the job of N.

The Anthropic Principle points out that this is a case of metaphorically speaking about the probability of similar or even identical universes, not our universe in sensu strictu.
The Anthropic Principle is not a poor argument. It rather points out the poor understanding of probability most people show.
Once a singular event (as opposed to probabilistic quantum states) occurred, there is no such thing as a probability. These events did occur no matter their original probability.
Probability is, in a way, the antithesis of causality, so asking why or how some improbable event occurred is a meaningless statement, even compared to other, theoretically more probable (ante facto) events. It is word salad emerging from a poor understanding of what one is talking about. Probabilities mean exactly that we cannot predict or explain why one event occurs and others do not. The maximum we can do is making out or measuring possible states and guessing or measuring their relative frequency of occurrence in repeated processes. That does not mean we can predict any given single event (hence the Gambler's Fallacy).
Accordingly, stating that it just makes no sense to ask how in the world this improbable state of the universe occurred is completely valid since, as a matter of fact, it obviously did occur. Any talk about the probability of our universe is necessarily metaphorical.

But if we applied that logic consistently, wouldn't that shut down a lot of scientific inquiry?  I.e., if we see a large boulder in the middle of the desert, would we say, "It is meaningless to talk of the probabilities of X, Y, or Z depositing this boulder here, because the fact is, it's here, it did happen."  And not rather, "Why is this boulder here?  Because X, Y, and Z seem like poor (or, unlikely) explanations, and there is surely a better one"?

@PeterRankin No, because the scientific inquiry tries to find explanations and causal chains, something which breaks down at the point we start to talk about "probability". We can still use this in the metaphorical meaning when comparing explanations but science does not exactly use probability as an argument. It chooses the easiest/fullest explanations, like the recent model of the transition of other stars being superior to a 9th planet as an explanation for the eccentricity of some objects circulating around the sun. It is not "more probable", it explains more with less assumptions.

@PeterRankin Every probabilistic model in science is purely descriptive but not explanatory. No kind of probability will ever tell you how the rock came into the desert.

+1 With the caveat that this notion of probability presumes at least a classical or frequentist reading and not a subjective interpretation (which of course is implied by the context of scientific discourse itself). It also rests on the metaphysics of figurative possible world semantics (which again is implied by the context of scientific discourse). My question is about your comments when you say that probabilistic models are purely descriptive and not explanatory. Should explanatory inference (IBE) be construed as subsuming both causal and statistical models by adding justificatory logic?

You ask:

Is the anthropic principle a cop-out?

No, if you take it to be nothing more than durable metaphysical speculation in the philosophy of physics that occurs because of the natural tendency to think of the universe in possible world semantics. Here are some facts about it.

It's a rational approach in the philosophy of physics, and cannot be tested because a universe by definition subsumes conceptually anything that interacts with it in a general sense.
It's natural to speculate about the origins of the universe if one embraces the Principle of Sufficient Reason. If there are properties of the universe as any other entity is wont to have, then clearly those properties need some sort of explanation.
Mathematical theories of physics are highly rational enterprises, and since they are frequently done divorced largely from empirical evidence, they are sometimes targets of criticism in the same way string theory (PhilSE) and dark matter are.

Therefore, if you mean as a term of abuse "cop-out" indicates that it, like the multiverse and modal realism is metaphysical and not scientific explanation (SEP), then yes, it is a cop-out. As Philip Klöcking has pointed out in his answer:

Accordingly, stating that it just makes no sense to ask how in the world this improbable state of the universe occurred is completely valid since, as a matter of fact, it obviously did occur. Any talk about the probability of our universe is necessarily metaphorical.

That is, from an empirical standpoint, there have been exactly 1 universe we can confirm by experience and experiment, and any non-subjective interpretation of probability (SEP) applied results in a non-sensical analysis. The existence of other universes is at best an instrument of reason, and at worst a dogmatic article of faith.

It depends.
What do you mean by a cop-out?
What is the Anthropic Principle trying to resolve? A short answer could be:  knowing how it is that the universe is so perfect to make life exists.
Trying to understand the universe in a scientific way, with numbers and logic seems a good approach. However, the question turns out to be why is the universe so perfect to make life exists?
Why is it that important that the universe makes life exists? Because of observation? Because the value we give to life?
In one way it does not appear to be a cop-out, as it seems to be a trial to understand accurately with mathematics. However, maybe it is a cop-out because it is trying to understand how and not why.

 Yes. It is a cop-out.

And without the hypothesis of multiple universes, the observation that if life hadn’t come into existence we wouldn’t be here has no significance. One doesn’t show that something doesn’t require explanation by pointing out that it is a condition of one’s existence. If I ask for an explanation of the fact that the air pressure in the transcontinental jet is close to that at sea level, it is no answer to point out that if it weren’t, I’d be dead.
— Thomas Nagel: Mind and Cosmos

To use the anthropic principle under the assumption of a single universe was one of the shenanigans introduced by Richard Dawkins. He popularized a mélange of badly distorted or misunderstood arguments taken from more serious atheist literature.
Such  arguments bedazzle and stump people; the tactic works if one presents them confidently and with an aura of intellectual superiority (see the sophist brothers in Plato's Euthydemus).
Much of the “New Atheists” literature was not only unreflective and shallow but also simply full of fallacies. It's dead now, but was once very well received, which is still shocking.

@MisterMiyagi no, it's not (if applied to a single universe). Of course, events with very, very, very low probability happen and have no other explanation than chance. But if that's the argument, you can stop right here. Just say you believe it's chance. The anthropic principle doesn't add anything, it doesn't make chance a more plausible explanation, and doesn't defuse the problems with accepting low probabilities. And if it somehow did, at least in one of the answers (which I read all) there would be a good explanation how, and not just mumbling.

@MisterMiyagi It would be fantastic if someone gave a real justification for the AP for a single universe, but until now, I've only read irrational mumbling defending the arch-sophist who invented it. Why don't you explain what the AP adds to just saying “events with very, very, very low probability happen”? After all these years, I've not seen a good argument that it adds anything. Your original answer is sophistical, since you conflate “denying an explanation” with “denying cause”. Explanation (unlike causation) is not just of an event, but of an event under a description!

The AP doesn’t say that chance is an explanation, though. But the original AP did, the original one! It gave a sensible argument that chance (or randomness) + selection can be an explanation, and in fact I agree. But this only works with multiple universes. Then Dawkins came along and amputated it, leaving the implicit claim that it still explains something.

If I'm on a jet with pressure being held at sea level, I also don't assume that its miraculous that physics allows that to happen, and that it's evidence that physics is fine-tuned for pressurizing airplanes.  It's easier to see that the plane pressurization is developed in a way to work with existing physics.  How is life any different?

@JMac There's a huge, huge difference between arguing that supernatural explanations are no good and should be dismissed (because of parsimony or other reasons), and insisting that the anthropic principle provides a sort of explanation. The anthropic principle (and again: not the original one, but Dawkins' variant of it) really doesn't explain anything and is (as so often with him) just a sophistical exercise of one-upmanship.

The anthropic principal seems like a weak argument against "random physics shouldn't have produced life" because there's a much better one. "Physics constants could have different values" is merely a thought experiment (more on that later). But, if we grant that, the anthropic principle is a perfectly good counter-argument.
To review, the original argument is: the physics of a new universe are random, and allow only a tiny chance life could form. So statistically, there must have been some external force selecting ours for life. The anthropic principle throws in a wrench by showing how statistics needs no external selection if there were a billion lifeless Big Bangs before us. Basically, it says "OK, but you still have to prove this is the only universe"(*). Since we're already talking about different ways universes can work, that seems like a reasonable ask.
But the good argument is that "different values for physics constants" has no basis. It probably comes from the 2017 book "A Fortunate Universe: Life in a Finely Tuned Cosmos" by for-real scientists Geraint Lewis and Luke Barnes. I haven't read it, but "finely tuned" is clearly a literary device and nothing more. You need a hook to sell a science book and taking the reader on a roller-coaster of how stars beat the odds to form the elements needed to make planets -- that's a good hook. The last chapter (I think) even talks about alternate universes. But they're just imagining that the weak nuclear force could have different values, to make it exciting.
For real, we've only seen the way physics works in this one universe. We have no evidence past that. It's possible the start of the universe rolls dice for each value, but we don't know. The current direction of physics -- I think? -- makes it seem more likely there are 3 super-basic thingies, determining everything else, with 2 states each (giving 8 universe types total). But we don't know. That the physics numbers are always what we see now is the most normal thing, science-wise. It's all pure speculation.
Back to "why use the anthropic principle?". The random physics argument is in a long line of science-themed proofs of god. I once read a 1975 book by Duane Gish claiming that recently discovered fossils of crazy creatures proved evolution didn't happen. In the 1980's it was popular to say the 2nd law of thermodynamics disproved evolution. When The Big Bang was popularized there were claims it proved Genisis. Today we've got Young Earth Creationists hard at work using mostly-real geology to show the earth could be only eight thousand years old. These arguments are meant to be persuasive rather than rigorous, so people arguing against them like to attack them on all levels. If some kid thinks different physics universes feels "truthy", they can at least hear an argument against the next step, using the cool-sounding anthropic principle.
(*) Or we could show that other universes also support life at rates way too high than the odds predict, once again suggesting an external force. But that seems too much in the weeds, especially since science fiction suggests we'd see "nearby" habitable universes first, making our statistical test unreliable.
